# SQL Like ending in specific string %5% vs. %25%

Tags: sql

Hi and thanks in advance. 
I have a few case statements that calculate "Quantity" based on the text in "ProductName."

```
Productname                Quantity
Product1 - 5 pack          should = 5
Product2 - 10 pack         should = 10
Product3 - 25 pack         should = 25
```

My case works well, however, when I do this: When `productname like '%5 pack' then quantity(5)` it also sees this as "25 pack" because of the wildcard and thus I get incorrect values. They all end exactly as seen here "- [##] pack"

Comment: maybe it would be best if you try to identify what's between the dash `-` and `pack`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: If it's a case expression you could search for 25 before searching for 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case expression are searched in order. Put the more restrictive ones first.

Or if all the names fit the pattern you describe then this will probably work.

```
select cast(left(right(ProductName, 7), 2) as int) as Quantity from ...
```

Or you could use `substring` with a negative start position potentially.

```
cast(substring(ProductName, -7, 2) as int)
```

Many other options as well...

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am going to try out some other ways to see how they work, but changing the order in the case worked well so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better answer, but I started thinking in order of operation and it turns out that if I use this first in the statement `When productname like '%25 pack'` then use `When productname like '%5 pack'` everything seems to be working.

I'd be interested in knowing if there is an easier or better way of doing this.

Comment: So, you need to know every single option of number for the packs?. Can you tell us the RDBMS that you are using?

Comment: Obviously the disadvantage to a hardcoded list (inside a case expression) is that you have to change the code when you add a new product that doesn't fit the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data, you could use LIKE '%[ -]5 pack'. (Notice that inside the brackets is a space and a hyphen.)

This keeps you from having to order the case statement correctly.